# Name Broken Horizontal Bar Chart Plotly JS

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am trying to create a nice horizontal bar with plotlyjs but the lines name are been broken.

[Horizontal Bar Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB2b4.png)

The last line is impossible to put a full name. How can i break in 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!!!
As it is used on Vertical Barchart,
https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/

It can be done on horizontal, also.
What i've done is:

```
name.replace(" ", "<br>")
```

[HorizontalBar Better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23mWd.png)